# Parsing GET request parameters in a URL that contains another URL

Tags: php, get, request, urlencode

Here is the url:

```
http://localhost/test.php?id=http://google.com/?var=234&key=234
```

And I can't get the full $_GET['id'] or $_REQUEST['d'].

```
<?php
print_r($_REQUEST['id']); 
//And this is the output http://google.com/?var=234
//the **&key=234** ain't show 
?>
```

Comment: try to get `$_REQUEST['key']` or change the URL to `http://localhost/test.php?id=http://google.com/?var=234&amp;key=234`

Comment: @teneff How can I get all $_GET without specifying the 'id'?

Comment: just use `$_GET` :) like `print_r($_GET);`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
$get_url = "http://google.com/?var=234&key=234";
$my_url = "http://localhost/test.php?id=" . urlencode($get_url);
```

$my_url outputs:

```
http://localhost/test.php?id=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2F%3Fvar%3D234%26key%3D234
```

So now you can get this value using `$_GET['id']` or `$_REQUEST['id']` (decoded).

```
echo urldecode($_GET["id"]);
```

Output

```
http://google.com/?var=234&key=234
```

To get every GET parameter:

```
foreach ($_GET as $key=>$value) {
  echo "$key = " . urldecode($value) . "<br />\n";
  }
```

`$key` is GET key and `$value` is GET value for `$key`.

Or you can use alternative solution to get array of GET params

```
$get_parameters = array();
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $pairs = explode('&', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
  foreach($pairs as $pair) {
    $part = explode('=', $pair);
    $get_parameters[$part[0]] = sizeof($part)>1 ? urldecode($part[1]) : "";
    }
  }
```

`$get_parameters` is same as url decoded `$_GET`.

Comment: How can I get all $_GET without specifying the 'id'? So that I can automatically read all $_GET request?

Comment: <code>$get_parameters = array();
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $pairs = explode('&', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
  foreach($pairs as $pair) {
    $part = explode('=', $pair);
    $get_parameters[$part[0]] = urldecode($part[1]);
    }
  }</code>

Warning ! You have to test if (count($part) > 1) before get some undefined offset.

Answer (score 9):

While creating url encode them with [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

```
$val=urlencode('http://google.com/?var=234&key=234')

<a href="http://localhost/test.php?id=<?php echo $val ?>">Click here</a>
```

and while fetching decode it wiht [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

Answer (score 2):

You may have to use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) on the string 'http://google.com/?var=234&key=234'

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and ended up using `parse_url` and `parse_str`, which as long as the URL in the parameter is correctly url encoded (which it definitely should) allows you to access both all the parameters of the actual URL, as well as the parameters of the encoded URL in the query parameter, like so:

```
$get_url = "http://google.com/?var=234&key=234";
$my_url = "http://localhost/test.php?id=" . urlencode($get_url);

function so_5645412_url_params($url) {
    $url_comps = parse_url($url);
    $query = $url_comps['query'];

    $args = array();
    parse_str($query, $args);

    return $args;
}

$my_url_args = so_5645412_url_params($my_url); // Array ( [id] => http://google.com/?var=234&key=234 )
$get_url_args = so_5645412_url_params($my_url_args['id']); // Array ( [var] => 234, [key] => 234 )
```

Answer (score 1):

you use bad character like ? and & and etc ...

edit it to new code

see this links

- http://antoine.goutenoir.com/blog/2010/10/11/php-slugify-a-string/
- http://sourcecookbook.com/en/recipes/8/function-to-slugify-strings-in-php

also you can use urlencode

```
$val=urlencode('http://google.com/?var=234&key=234')
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct php way is to use parse_url()

```
http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php
```

(from php manual)

This function parses a URL and returns an associative array containing any of the various components of the URL that are present.

This function is not meant to validate the given URL, it only breaks it up into the above listed parts. Partial URLs are also accepted, parse_url() tries its best to parse them correctly.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])){
    echo "https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]$_SERVER[QUERY_STRING]";
}else{
    echo "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]$_SERVER[QUERY_STRING]";
}
```